# JavaSnap login issues

Tags: java, snapchat

I can't seem to log in to Snapchat using the JavaSnap API, https://github.com/hatboysam/JavaSnap, even when I provide the correct login information.

The code I used:

```
Snapchat sc = Snapchat.login(usernameLogin.getText(), passwordLogin.getText());

if (sc != null) {
   System.out.println("Login Successful");
} else {
   System.out.println("Login Failed");
}
```

By looking at the example Main class. logging in is successful when sc is not null, however, it is always null here.

The logging in part in the example Main class.

```
snapchat = Snapchat.login(username, password);
if (snapchat != null) {
    System.out.println("Logged in.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Failed to log in.");
    return;
}
```

Comment: have you tried to replace _usernameLogin.getText(), passwordLogin.getText()_ with values and test again ? try to print result of fields my be contains spaces.

Comment: I just did, and it still didn't work :/

Comment: No JavaFX relationship.

Comment: @M.leRutte Fixed! Now please remove your downvote.